# Custom typing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.8, typing

Custom typing in Python 3.8

I have:

/zoo.py

```
from typing import List

class Zoo(object):

   animals: List
```

/animal.py

```
from zoo import Zoo

class Animal(object):
   
  zoo: Zoo
```

How do I determine the type of data in the first file without the cyclicity of imports? I want to get the following

/zoo.py

```
from typing import List
from animal import Animal

class Zoo(object):

   animals: List[Animal]
```

In large projects, cyclicality interferes. How to use typing correctly in such cases

Comment: So why doesn't your intended solution work? Looks fine to me.

Comment: In large projects, cyclicality interferes. How to use typing correctly in such cases. When there are many classes, and it is difficult to connect - it is not always possible to import them without cyclicity

Comment: Especially since you're not actually invoking the imported type in the class definition, you can just do `import animal` and `animals: List[animal.Animal]`, and that should work fine